# MySQL get data of most recent related record

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables (for the purposes of this question) companies and invoices. A company can have multiple invoices and they are related by a company_id auto-increment. I'm looking to get data from the most recent invoice for each company that has an invoice.
I don't just want the date of the most recent related record but various data from that related record.

I tried a few different methods but the query I've got at the moment is horrible... it causes me pain to have to resort to something like this in a relational database.
Here's the query...

```
SELECT `companies`.`company_name`, `invoices_latest`.`data`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`invoices_latest`.`data`, '~', 1), '~', -1) AS `last_invoice_stamp`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`invoices_latest`.`data`, '~', 2), '~', -1) AS `last_invoice_id`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`invoices_latest`.`data`, '~', 3), '~', -1) AS `last_invoice_reference`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`invoices_latest`.`data`, '~', 4), '~', -1) AS `last_invoice_amount` 
FROM `companies` 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT `company_id`, MAX(CONCAT_WS('~', `invoice_stamp`, `invoice_id`, `reference`, CONCAT_WS(' ', `currency`, FORMAT(`amount`, 2)))) AS `data` 
FROM `invoices`
GROUP BY `invoices`.`company_id`
) AS `invoices_latest` ON `companies`.`company_id`=`invoices_latest`.`company_id`
WHERE `invoices_latest`.`data` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `companies`.`company_name`
```

Concatenating the data in the derived table then splitting it out in the parent query is horrible but it's the only way I've found to achieve what I'm looking for.

I tried this...

```
SELECT `companies`.`company_id`, `companies`.`company_name`, `invoices_latest`.`invoice_id`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`invoices_latest`.`invoice_stamp`)
FROM `companies`
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT `company_id`, `invoice_id`, `invoice_stamp`
FROM `invoices`
ORDER BY `invoice_stamp` DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
) AS `invoices_latest` ON `companies`.`company_id`=`invoices_latest`.`company_id`
WHERE `invoices_latest`.`invoice_id` IS NOT NULL
```

But it doesn't work as expected and only returns 1 row - because I believe the LIMIT in the derived table actually is applied to the parent query. It's a shame you can't do something like that as it would be an easy to read solution.

Is there a better alternative to the horrible concatenation I've got going on above?

Answer (score 0):

```
select company,*, invoice.*
from company, invoice
where company.company_id = invoice.company_id
and (invoice.company_id, invoice.date) in (
  select company_id, max(date) from invoices group by company_id
);
```

Comment: That's a nice solution but seems to take an age compared to my horrible method above... 76 seconds vs 0.0142. And I have indexes on invoices.company_id, invoices.invoice_id (primary), invoices.invoice_stamp, companies.company_id (primary). I presume it's the subquery in the WHERE...IN clause, they always seem to take a while. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Add a field (latest_invoice_id) to your company table and maintain it by means of a trigger with every insert, update or delete in the invoices table.

Comment: /* Here was a dumb idea which I just deleted. */

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to approach it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoice` WHERE `company_id`=ID ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 25;
```

if you are not specifying the ID in the command, you can select all company IDs and do the same thing for each pretty much with a similar command:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoice` WHERE `company_id` IN(SELECT `company_id` FROM `companies`) ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: Without the LIMIT clause, that returns all invoices in the system. Most companies have more than 1 invoice and I'm just looking to return the most recent invoice (and invoice value and various other fields from the invoices table) for each company. Also I do need to structure the query `FROM companies` because I am looking to add in other joins to other related data from my companies table. Cheers!